# Python Plot Data From CSV

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BBIu.png)

Hi everyone, I'm trying to plot a graph data from CSV. There are 7 columns in my CSV. I've already plot the Genre column with my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('booksellers.csv')
genre = df['Genre']
countFiction = 0
countNonFiction = 0
for i in genre:
    if i == "Fiction":
        countFiction+=1
    else:
        countNonFiction+=1

labels = 'Fiction','Non Fiction'
sizes = [countFiction,countNonFiction]
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes,labels=labels,startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

Now, I want to plot another 2 columns which are 'Author' and the average of 'User Rating'. If the Author is duplicated, how can I get only one Author with their average user rating? And also what kind of graph is compatible with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can iterate line by line 

from statistics import mean 

data = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    author = row['Author']
    if not author in data:
        data[author] = {'rating':[]}
    data[author].append(row['User Rating'])

rates_by_authors = {}
for k in data.keys()
    rates_by_authors[k] = means(data[k])

# after create the data with that code

# you can use list(rates_by_authors.keys()) that is author's list as a X axis
# you can use list(rates_by_authors.values() ) that is average of ratings by authors list as a Y axis
```

Comment: I just tried your code but it didn't work. Can you double-check please?

Comment: Actually that is not totatly true code, it is like a pseudocode you should some parts for example, row['rating']) to row['User Rating']), I changed, i think that is enough

Comment: It shows invalid syntax here: data[author] = {'rating';[]}